# How to check if a div with href="something" has certain class with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, materialize

I'd like to check if a div with a particular `href` has a certain class too. I've coded this nav:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul class="normal-nav hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a class="" href="#chi">Chi Siamo</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#dirigenza">Dirigenza</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#squadre">Squadre</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#orariPrezzi">Orari e Prezzi</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#modulistica">Modulistica</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#contatti">Contattaci</a></li>
            <li><a class="" href="#fotogallery">Fotogallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

A class `active` is added to the `<a>` element, relative to location on which the user has scrolled down, so that `<a>` looks like this:

```
<a class="active" href="#dirigenza">Dirigenza</a>
```

I'd like to check continuously which element in normal-nav `<ul>` has class `active` (I've scrollFire() JQuery plugin):

```
$('body').scrollfire({
    // Offsets
    offset: 0,
    topOffset: 0,
    bottomOffset: 0,
    onScrollAlways: function(elm, distance_scrolled) {
    },
});
```

and do some stuff if `<a>` active element is that one with `href="#chi"`, `href="#dirigenza"` and so on.

How can I do this?

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772924/get-url-path-and-add-class-active-on-li?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Try using the [`hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$("a.active")` to get the current a marked as active.
Then you can use `$("a.active").attr("href")` to get the value of the href for that active element and use it in a if or switch statement to manage different cases.

```
var activeHrefValue = $("a.active").attr("href");
if (activeHrefValue == "theValueToBeChecked") {
   doSomething();
}
```

In your particular case I think this can be a good solution:

```
$('body').scrollfire({
    // Offsets
    offset: 0,
    topOffset: 0,
    bottomOffset: 0,
    onScrollAlways: function(elm, distance_scrolled) {
        switch($("a.active").attr("href")){
            case "#chi":
                doSomething(elm);
                break;
            case "...":
                doSomethingElse(elm);
                break;
            default: 
                doDefaultSomething(elm);
        }
    },
});
```

That switch part can be replaced with a series of if-else statements based on your necessities.

Comment: Works great! Thanks LucioB. unfortunately I can't give you reputation!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.active[href='#chi']")
```

Will select **all** `a` with class `active` and whose `href` is `#chi`.

```
$("a.active[href='#chi'], a.active[href='#dirigenza']")
```

Use this one for multiple `hrefs`

```
$("a.active[href='#chi']").length
```

will give the number of matching elements.

Comment: Good,but I think that Lucio' answer is more complete. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass) method:

```
$('body').scrollfire({
    // Offsets
    offset: 0,
    topOffset: 0,
    bottomOffset: 0,
    onScrollAlways: function(elm, distance_scrolled) {
      if($(elm).hasClass('testingclass')){
         console.log('testingclass');
      }
    },
});
```